# Angularjs post form with file input type to php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms

I have a form similar to this:

```
<form>
    ...

    <input type="text" ng-model="data.textInput">
    <input type="file" ng-model="data.imageInput">

    ...
<form>
```

When I submit the form, I use the script below to post it in a php file:

```
$http({
                url: 'url_to_php_file.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $scope.data, 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
                }
            });
```

Then, in my php file I can access the text data like this:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

echo $_POST['textInput'];
```

Till here, everything works as it should, but the problem is to access the file input type data. I have seen some examples that consist in uploading the file before calling the http request, but they don't show how to handle the request in server.

What I want to realize is to encode the file using `base64_encode`, in order to upload it in a database. When I post a form without angularjs, but in the classic way, I use this line to encode the file, and then upload it in the db:

```
$imageInput= base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']));
```

How can achieve this using angularjs?

Comment: Need to use FormData API and set special configuration for ajax. This is not hard to research .... `angular upload`

Comment: Ok, but how to handle this in the php file? How to encode it in base64?

Comment: you don't need to do anything with base64 if you use FormData API... will use `$_FILES` in php. The data won't be sent as json, you don't want `$http` to do any transformations... please do the research.